# jQuery blur if new focused element is not a child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `blur` event attached to a container (in this case, a table cell) with one *or more* clickable items (e.g. input fields and buttons).

Two things can happen in my cell-embedded form. If a value changes in one of the input fields, the form is processed. If a value hasn't changed, but focus is lost, then the form is cleared.

I don't want the cell to `blur` if the user has clicked another item within the cell.

Here's something I attempted - checking the number of focused children in the `blur` event.

#### HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="edit">
            <input type="text"></input>
            <input type="checkbox"></input>
            <button>Test</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('table').on('change', '#edit input', function () {
    alert('An input field has changed');
});

$('table').on('blur', '#edit', function () {>
    if ($(this).children(':focus').length == 0) {
        alert('The user has clicked away from the form');
    } else {
        alert('The user hasn\'t finish editing yet');
    }
});
```

But unfortunately, the length of the focused children is always reported as 0!

Then I tried

```
$('body').not('#edit, #edit > *').on('focus', function () {
    alert('The user has clicked something else');
});
```

But this doesn't work at all! And I'm also dubious about it because I require the `change` handler to be fired before the `focus` handler so the form doesn't get cancelled if the user has made changes.

Here's a jsfiddle for you lazy kids: http://jsfiddle.net/QmVsr/

Comment: The problem is the order of events - the focus to the target element is set only after `blur` event is fired from the previous element

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use a timer based approach

```
$('table').on('blur', '#edit', function () {
    var timer = setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('The user has clicked away from the form');
    }, 20);
    $(this).closest('td').data('blurTimer', timer)
}).on('focus', '#edit', function () {
    clearTimeout($(this).closest('td').data('blurTimer'))
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YhGEJ/)

*Note: While debugging prefer console logging instead of alerts*

Comment: This doesn't work on Google Chrome v29 - besides, I don't like the timeout because it would be temperamental if the user's browser is too slow